# Profile2 -> Update node on submit?

Tags: 7, forms, users

I have a specific user role with a profile attached too them. Every user with this role has a corresponding node with the same information that can be found on the user's profile. Now I'm looking for a way to keep the two in sync, so if you change the user's profile, it would update the corresponding node as well. Is there a way to hook in to Profile2's form submit handler, or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just add your own submit handler to the form you're talking about rather than trying to override an existing one?

Comment: I tried using hook_form_profile2_form_alter to add another submit handler: `$form['#submit'][] = 'accounts_profile_form_submit';` Though that didn't seem to work.

Comment: Ack, nevermind. Since I'm working different user roles, I wasn't logged in as admin, so devel wasn't showing up. Stupid.

Comment: Ah, you know devel has permissions to let all users see it?

Comment: Yep. Though I had entirely forgotten to change them. Thanks though!